# Installing stackify in linux

Tags: jprofiler, stackify

The installation guide of `Stackify` states that we have to modify the `catalina.sh` of `tomcat` file to add the java agent. But in a `spring-boot` app, where can I find the tomcat location to modify the file.

I changed the `application.properties` file to set the custom location for `tomcat` by setting `server.tomcat.basedir`.

How can I change the `catalina.sh` file now?

Answer (score 1):

Should be able to do the command `cd $CATALINA_HOME/bin` to get to the folder that contains the catalina.sh. After that you can add `CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -javaagent:enter_path_stackify_apm_jar"` to it.

Comment: but `echo $CATALINA_HOME` displays empty output

Comment: What is the command you are using to run the spring boot application? you will need to add the --javaagent:"stackify/java/lib/stackify-java-apm.jar" to the command